# Does this partial convexity imply divergence at infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

Let $g:(-\infty,0] \to [0,\infty)$ be a $C^2$ strictly decreasing function, $g(0)=0$.

Suppose that there exist a sequence $\lambda_n \to -\infty$  such that
$$
g(\frac{x + y}{2}) \le \frac{g(x) + g(y)}{2}  \, \,\, \, \text{ whenever } \, \, x,y \le 0 \, \, \, \text{ and  } x+y=\lambda_n.
$$

> Does $\lim_{x \to -\infty}g(x)=+\infty$?

If we were assuming the stronger assumption that $g(\frac{x + y}{2}) \le \frac{g(x) + g(y)}{2}$ whenever $x,y \in (-\infty,0]$, then the answer would positive:

Indeed, full midpoint-convexity implies convexity, and a convex function lies above its tangent. ($g$ have a point with negative derivative, since it is strictly decreasing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the conjecture is true.  Since $\lambda_n \to -\infty$ we can choose a subsequence $(\lambda_{n_k})$ such that
$$
 \lambda_{n_k} < 2 \lambda_{n_{k-1}}
$$
for all $k$. Choosing $x=0$ and $y= \lambda_{n_k}$ in your condition and the monotonicity of $g$ gives
$$
 g(\lambda_{n_{k-1}}) \le  g\left( \frac 12 \lambda_{n_k}\right) \le \frac 12 g(\lambda_{n_k})
$$
so that
$$
 g(\lambda_{n_k}) \ge 2 g(\lambda_{n_{k-1}}) \ge 2^2 g(\lambda_{n_{k-2}})
\ge \ldots \ge 2^{k-1}  g(\lambda_{n_{1}}) \, .
$$